# How to keep two Lots when matching on unique combinations across multiple R dataframe columns

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, unique

I am trying to return two sets of unique combinations when matched on unique combinations of multiple variables.

Specifically, I want to return two "Lot" numbers for each unique combination of "Var_1", "Var_2", and "Var_3".

Example starting dataframe:

```
my_data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Var_1   Var_2   Var_3   Lot
A   B   E   X
A   B   E   Y
A   B   E   Z
A   C   E   X
A   C   E   Y
A   C   E   Z
A   C   D   X
A   C   D   Y
A   C   D   Z
")

my_data


#Desired Output
my_output <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Var_1   Var_2   Var_3   Lot
A   B   E   X
A   B   E   Y
A   C   E   X
A   C   E   Y
A   C   D   X
A   C   D   Y
")

my_output
```

I've tried using the following method:

```
  my_data %>% count(Var_1, Var_2, Var_3, Lot, sort = TRUE) %>% top_n(2, n)
```

(Outcome:  Returned all three Lots across matched variables, not two as desired)

Comment: You need to `group_by`, not `count`, like this: `my_data |> group_by(Var_1, Var_2, Var_3) |> slice_head(n = 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slice_head` instead to get only the top two.

```
my_data %>% slice_head(n = 2,by = c(Var_1, Var_2, Var_3))

#   Var_1 Var_2 Var_3 Lot
# 1     A     B     E   X
# 2     A     B     E   Y
# 3     A     C     E   X
# 4     A     C     E   Y
# 5     A     C     D   X
# 6     A     C     D   Y
```